# Javascript Frame Animation Flashing on Load

Tags: javascript, animation

Here is the CodePen of the animation. It flashes for the first cycle of the frames displayed. Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Any help would be very much appreciated!

```js
let frames = [
"http://i.imgur.com/QhvQuaG.png", 
"http://i.imgur.com/VjSpZfB.png",
"http://i.imgur.com/Ar1czX0.png",
"http://i.imgur.com/ROfhCv4.png",
"http://i.imgur.com/6B32vk7.png",
"http://i.imgur.com/2t5MWOL.png",
"http://i.imgur.com/a9wLBbc.png",
"http://i.imgur.com/OBKcW8f.png",
"http://i.imgur.com/RC6wLgw.png",
"http://i.imgur.com/2HyI8yS.png"];

let startframe = 0;

function arrow(){
let start = Date.now();
let timer = setInterval(function() {
  let timePassed = Date.now() - start;
  if (timePassed >= 20000) {
    clearInterval(timer); // finish the animation after 2 seconds
    return;
  }
  move();
}, 200); 
}

function move(){  
  if (startframe==(frames.length-1)){
    startframe=0;
  } else {
    startframe++;
  }
    // document.getElementById('continue').style.backgroundSize = "100%";
    document.getElementById('continue').style.background = "url(" + frames[startframe] +")";  
    document.getElementById('continue').style.backgroundSize = "100%"; 
}
```

```css
#continue {
  width: 80px;
    height:40px;
}
```

```html
<div onclick = "arrow()">Start</div>

<div id="continue"></div>
```

Comment: Where is the link?

Comment: @ikbel Thank you!

Comment: no problem, check out my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the network tab of your browser dev tools, you'll see that the flashing happens when the browser is loading the images.

You should preload all the images before starting the animation, like so:

```js
let frames = [
  "http://i.imgur.com/QhvQuaG.png", 
  "http://i.imgur.com/VjSpZfB.png",
  "http://i.imgur.com/Ar1czX0.png",
  "http://i.imgur.com/ROfhCv4.png",
  "http://i.imgur.com/6B32vk7.png",
  "http://i.imgur.com/2t5MWOL.png",
  "http://i.imgur.com/a9wLBbc.png",
  "http://i.imgur.com/OBKcW8f.png",
  "http://i.imgur.com/RC6wLgw.png",
  "http://i.imgur.com/2HyI8yS.png"
]

var startframe = 0
var images = [] // This array will contain all the downloaded images

function preloadImages() {
    var loaded = 0
    for (i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) {
        images[i] = new Image();
        images[i].onload = function() {
            loaded += 1
            if (loaded >= frames.length) {
              arrow()
            }
        }
        images[i].src = frames[i]
    }
}

function arrow(){
  let start = Date.now();
  let timer = setInterval(function() {
    let timePassed = Date.now() - start;
    if (timePassed >= 20000) {
      clearInterval(timer) // finish the animation after 2 seconds
      return;
    }
    move()
  }, 200)
}

function move() {  
  var c  = document.getElementById('continue')
  c.innerHTML = '' // remove the content of #continue
  
  // Insert the already exiting image from the images array
  // into the container instead of downloading again with css
  c.append(images[startframe])
  if (startframe >= frames.length - 1) {
    startframe = 0
  }
  else {
    startframe++
  }
}
```

```css
#continue {
  width: 80px;
  height:40px;
}

#continue > img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div onclick = "preloadImages()">Start</div>

<div id="continue"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the images need to be loaded when viewed for the first time. It is possible to pre-load images in different ways. [Here are three ways to preload images.](https://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/)